# Set an audio length equal to another file using ffmpeg

Tags: python, signal-processing, audio-processing

Is it possible to set an audio length equal to another file using Python? (Does not matter if the end part of the signal should be deleted)

For example:

- Audio file 1 = 2 seconds length
- Audio file 2 = 120 seconds length

export Audio file 2 = 2 seconds length

Since Audio file 1 is a "flac" and Audio file 2 is in "WAV" format, I am confused. I don't know with which library or commands it is possible to edit files.
In addition, I have more that 2000 audio files that are 1~6 seconds in length and need to import them separately each time. The coding results must be:

Each time new audio entries arrive, set the  Audio file 2 length equal to what Audio file 1.

Comment: What format should the modified file be?

Comment: The output format should be FLAC (same as the first Audio File).

Comment: Yes, it is possible to set the length of an audio file equal to the length of another audio file using Python. To do this, you will need to use a Python library that provides functions for reading and writing audio files, such as scipy or pydub.